# How do you load an audio asset from "the standard locations" in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am trying to play an audio asset in my Xamarin.Forms app, and following [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/adding-sound-xamarin-forms-app/) guide I always get a System.NullReferenceException. I have placed my two audio files, "device_off.mp3" and "device_on.mp3", in the Android "Assets" folder with the build action AndroidAsset and in the Apple Resources folder with the build action BundleResource. According to the tutorial, I should be able to simply reference the file names to load the files since they are in what Microsoft there terms "the standard locations". My code to play the audio files is as follows:

```cs
using(var player = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current)
{
     if(color == Color.Green)
     {
          string filepath = "device_on.mp3";
          player.Load(filepath);
          player.Play();
     }else
     {
          string filepath = "device_off.mp3";
          player.Load(filepath);
          player.Play();
     }
}
```

What should I be doing differently so I no longer get a System.NullReferenceException when the program reaches the line "player.Load(filepath);"?

Comment: that article was written in 2017 and the plugin hasn't been updated in ~2 years.  Look at the Xamarin Media Manager instead - https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager

Comment: This was literally a godsend thank you so much it's all working now :)